# How to convert or encrypt datetime or unix time to 3 characters or letters

Tags: php, datetime, encryption

I have only 3 characters space i want to convert  datetime  or unix time using php

Can anyone share any logic, no matter its mathematical calculation or anything

Comment: [How to ask questions on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What is a "character or letter"? How should this conversion work?

Comment: Space (disk or memory) isn't exactly expensive these days, so why this limitation?

Comment: My requirement is for  csv export, i have a field where i want only to show 3 unique characters. and  as datetime is unique, i want to convert the datetime to 3 characters

Comment: If the requirement is for csv export, that's no explanation for this restriction because you can output a formatted date value in csv... if you compress or encrypt it, then any application or user trying to view that field will have to decompress/decrypt it, or it will be a meaningless field to them.... so what are the requirements of the user for importing that CSV into any other application?

Comment: Hi Mark , thanks for explanation. i will decrypt that field value again in same manner as we do in exporting, so its only for visibility for csv file. internally we will use datetime field in our magento plateform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't do it - looking at the math

Printable ASCII Chars are 33-126 or 93 possible options for each character space - which I assume is what you're using for CSV (and a couple of these in the range won't be usable single quote/double quote type deals)

So your maximum possible combinations would be 804,357 with 3 of the ASCII printable characters.  So then I thought what if we had an earliest time (not started at 1970); however 3 characters can only account for enough seconds in about 9.3 days.  So that's out of the game.

Even if you could use all 8 bits in an ascii character - you'd only be able to account for 16,777,216 seconds or 194.1 days.  You may be able to stretch this out with some business logic (aka time will never be before 8 AM or after 4 PM and only on weekdays) which would give enough values in a maximum use scenario of a year or two.  But the code restrictions and complexity - you'd be shooting yourself in your foot to make it work, even if you could as you'd need non-printable characters too (such as carriage return, tabs, etc).

As a side note, just did an echo of time and it's 1,412,620,205 (with just seconds).  Event if you divide that by 60 and went just to minutes you'd be way shy.

Basically - can't do it for a CSV export scenario.  Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for explanation airtech, you cleared my lot of points regarding encryption. i come to one logic now, but confused on probability at end.

Comment: Thanks for explanation @airtech, you cleared my lot of points regarding encryption. i come to one logic now, but confused on probability at end.    day  -- 31

month --  12

year -- 50

hour -- 24

min -- 60

sec  - 60    we have  6 things, we can make 3 pairs for subtraction, mean can get 3 characters. we will not use ASCII characters, we will use normal A-Z and a-z and 1-4, total 60 values,bcs we have 60 max.  


S = 19

a = minutes

b= day


a-b = 19 or

b-a = 19

a<61

b<31

now probability issue comes up, i have to solve this